# Testing Controller Actions With Expectations With Check For Changes in Count When Using `let`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

I'm in the process of refactoring some specs to use `let` instead of instance variables.

I'm running up against a problem with a controller spec:

```
describe "#destroy" do

    let(:gallery){ create(:gallery) }

    context "when not authenticated" do

      it {
        expect{
          delete :destroy, id: gallery
        }.to_not change{ Gallery.count }
        should redirect_to new_user_session_path
      }

    end
end
```

It seems that the problem comes from using 'let`because it lazy-creates gallery the first time it is referenced which in this case is inside the expect block. So the`Gallery.count` actually increases from 0 to 1, causing the test to fail. At the moment, the test fails because of the RSpec implementation rather than the code it tests.

Obviously I could go back to creating the galley in the `before` block and storing it in an instance variable, but this feels a bit hacky. A work-around is to add a before block thath references the gallery, causing it to be evaluated before the expect block:

```
before { gallery }
```

What is the best way to structure this spec?

**How should I structure this test?**

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant way, but this works for me:

```
describe "#destroy" do

  let(:gallery){ create(:gallery) }

  context "when not authenticated" do

    it {
      gallery
      expect{
        delete :destroy, id: gallery
      }.to_not change{ Gallery.count }
      should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    }

  end
end
```

If you are not varying the value of `gallery` across tests in the group, then there's really no need to use let() in the first place, so you could just do the before block as you mentioned and it's a little more readable:

```
describe "#destroy" do

  context "when not authenticated" do

    before { @gallery = create(:gallery) }

    it {
      expect{
        delete :destroy, id: @gallery
      }.to_not change{ Gallery.count }
      should redirect_to new_user_session_path
    }

  end
end
```